# Cronjob with nodejs for sending email

Tags: node.js, cron

Iam looking for node time scheduler for sending email to users and found this cronjob , but it seems not working below is my code with function calling API

Iam very new to node js,  can any one please help me with this 'On running the server it doesn't get into 'app.get' function itself.

```
  var cron = require('cron');
  var cronJob = cron.job("0 */10 * * * *", function(){

  app.get('/email',function(req, res) {
  console.log("second")
  console.log(req.body.htmltag);
    db.collection('UserData', function(err, collection) {
      collection.find({},{email:1}).toArray(function(err, items) {
      res.send(items);

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://riyas.1012@gmail.com:aslihaabu@3734@smtp.gmail.com');

      for(i=0;i<items.length;i++)
{
var mailOptions = {
    from: ' <svatsan53@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to: items[i].email, // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
    html:  req.body.htmltag // html body
};
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
            }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    })


        }
        });
    });
});
}); 
cronJob.start();
```

Comment: Cron Job + Event listener? Remove that event listener for HTTP get.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get('/email',function(req, res) {})
```

this code is defined a router `/email`
i think you are calling the api `/email`, but this code it's wrong

maybe you should do like this:

```
var request = require('request');

request.get('/email', function (err, res, body) {
  if (err || res.statusCode !== 200) {
    throw new Error('invalid url');
  }

  console.log(body);
  // send email here
});
```

Try the cron code like this:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

check the [usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) for cron module

hope it could help

Comment: I can send mail with above code but my  problem is i need to fetch email id's from DB and send mail to all users. i modified the code  given by you but it is not working.! any other ideas pls.

Comment: what do you wanna do on `app.get('/email',function(req, res) {...}`

Comment: i think you better refactor your code, extract the 'send mail' code, then you got the simply code in the cron job, then you can handle it well