# How to send Email based on date in database using nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular5

Im having bulk of data in database with column scheduling date In which Im having date for mailing.Once the server start it will automatically send mail to the person based on scheduled time in database

Comment: SO is a place to ask about specific problems with your code. Your question is too broad. What have you tried to far? What is the problem with your approach?

Comment: automatic mail sending based on date in database

Comment: That’s what you already said in your question. But you do not say what specific problem you have. How do you store the scheduled time in the database? How do you search for those times for which an email should already have been send but was not up to now? And what is the specific problem you have with your current approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126341/cronjob-with-nodejs-for-sending-email

Answer (score 0):

you can save the scheduled time and email address into mongodb,and you can use this about [cron job](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) .